# Managers Adjustment Column in Forecasting

Tags: sales, forecasts-collaborative

We are looking to use the Managers Adjustment Column in Forecasting

After testing I get the **In** selection as it Totals the **In** values in the Commit Header

BUT

If I choose **Out** it does not add the **Out** Totals in the same way as In so what does Out do if anything

Thanks for your help as Always Andy